# Displaying in hex form instead of special characters

Tags: python, cryptography, hex, des

Here I want to get the texts in  this format : \x10\x11\x12\x13\x15\x14\x16\x17 , when displayed console how can i get that

```
   from pyDes import *
   import base64,string,random
   letters = [chr(i) for i in range(0,128)]
   key = '12345678'
   obj1= des(key, ECB)
   obj2 = des(key, ECB)
   text = '\x10\x11\x12\x13\x15\x14\x16\x17'
   print len(text)
   cipher_text = obj1.encrypt(text)
   decoded_text= obj2.decrypt(cipher_text)

   print; print 'plain text: ', text
   print; print 'Actual key: ', key 
   print; print 'Cipher text: ',cipher_text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the representation with `repr()` or the `%r` string formatting placeholder:

```
print '\nplain text: %r' % text
print '\nActual key: %r' % key 
print '\nCipher text: %r' % cipher_text
```

or you can explicitly encode the text to the `string_escape` encoding:

```
print '\nplain text:', text.encode('string_escape')
print '\nActual key:', key.encode('string_escape')
print '\nCipher text:', cipher_text.encode('string_escape')
```

Neither method will turn *all* bytes into `\xhh` escape sequences, only those outside of the printable ASCII character range.

To turn all characters into escape sequences, you'd have to use something like:

```
def tohex(string):
    return ''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in string)
```

and then

```
print '\nplain text:', tohex(text)
print '\nActual key:', tohex(key)
print '\nCipher text:', tohex(cipher_text)
```

Comment: +1 for `.encode('string_escape')`, that's neat! But this won't replace ASCII printables like `'h'` with `'\x68'` right?

Comment: @lmjohns3: no, it won't. That requires more work still, working on it.

Comment: Well that was owsome Thank you  :)